# How to format an encrypted sdcard?

Tags: encryption, format, micro-sd-card

I confused and try everything that I know but FAIL ! I have 32GB sd card, I want to format it. I don't care with the data, I want to use the memory card only. I'll tell the the story first:

I wanna encrypt my sd card in my tablet android, I encrypt it in settings and encrypt external drive. I wait in some hours but when encrypting finished, pop up tell the encrypt is error. Then I decrypt it and success. I then use it but failed. I unmount and inserting again but the system tell I must decrypt again (I have try but this loop loop again).

"SD card encryption is turned off. Turn on SD card encryption by tppig Turn on below. To use the SD card, tap continue to decrypt or tap turn on to turn on SD card encryption"

I have tap Continue and success decrypt but If inserting again, its look again.

I have try such us :

- format using windows [didn't working]
- format using software sd card formatter 4 (https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) [didn't working]
- wipe use disk wiper (erased option) [didn't working]
- use diskpart and clean all [didn't working] -> error occured
- deleting using ubuntu [didn't working]
- format use another phone and camera [didn't working]

Anyone could help me please? I just want to use my sdcard, I don't care with the data. Any help is appreciate

nb: I already factory reset my phone and formatting using my phone, but data still there not successed to format.

Comment: Please explain in what ways these things "didn't working".  You should be able to just blow away all partitions and start over, what actually happens when you try?  Sounds to me that the SD Card is probably just broken, have you tried another SD Card yet?

Comment: didn't working mean failed (still same). another sdcard no problemo. did u have a suggest?

Comment: What failed when you tried *"deleting using ubuntu"*, and what exactly did you try? Did `dd` just quietly give up, no messages at all, even in the syslog? And I'd also suggest  throwing away the card, especially since other cards are "no problemo", without any more details I'm guessing this one's just broken

Comment: @Xen2050 : deleting all file using ubuntu. I try delete all data but when I inserting the card the data still there not deleted. all case i have try and poin 1&2 (in up my story) tell me that the card write protected. poin 3-6 tell me the processed was successfully but nothing happened when I inserting the card again, the data still in the card. Do u have any suggest???

Comment: If the card's always write-protected, then it may be broken. Otherwise, in linux `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd[INSERT CARD LETTER HERE]` will overwrite any device that's writeable - be very careful to pick the right one, see dmesg/lsblk/syslog to verify

Answer (score 2):

**Diskpart**

This will take a *long* time (about an hour per 16 gigabytes)

1. Launch Command Prompt (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type in "`cmd`" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. Issue the "`diskpart`" command (this will launch the `diskpart` program and you will get a user account control notification, just hit "Yes")
3. Once you're in `diskpart`, run the command "`list disk`". A list will appear. Find the device you want to format.
4. Issue the "`select disk 1`" command but replace "1" with whatever device it was on the list
5. Issue a "`clean all`" command
6. Once it's done, go into "\Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools", double-click "Computer Management", then click on "Disk Management". Right-click on the device you're formatting and click "New Simple Volume". Choose "FAT32". Pick a drive letter and then click "Format". Wait a few seconds and then click Finish.